# INA126P gain is exactly double what it should be

Tags: amplifier

I'm using an INA126P, 8-dip chip on a breadboard.  I'm using +/- 15V supply, and the input I'm trying to amplify is a voltage divided input.  In the diagram below (sorry for the terrible quality), V1 = 0.3V (from a DC power supply), R = 47K.  No matter what I use for my gain resistor, the gain is actually double.  For example, my input voltage should be approximately 0.3mV and, without a gain resistor at all, I should see a gain of 5 to get me 1.5mV.  However, I see 3mV.  When I set the gain to, say, 13, using a 1K resistor, I expect to see 3.9mV but instead see 7.8.  I have tried a second INA126P and the same issue arises.

What might be going on?

[image]

Comment: Where is your input signal coming from?

Comment: If this is a DC signal, have you accounted for input offset voltages and input bias currents? Or does setting the input to 0V do you get 1.5mV? (ditto for 0.6 mV in, do you get 4.5 mV? ( input offsets) ot 6 mV (doubled gain)?

Comment: it is indeed a DC signal.  I haven't specifically accounted for the bias voltages, no.  I will check and get back to you

Comment: It does appear to be offset, that's awkward.  @BrianDrummond if you add it as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a DC signal, have you accounted for input offset voltages and input bias currents?

Or does setting the input to 0V do you get 1.5mV?

Given the data in the question, 0.6 mV in would either give you 4.5 mV (input offsets) or 6 mV (doubled gain) allowing you to distinguish between these possibilities.

Comment: As stated above: the issue was an offset voltage that was very unfortunate in its magnitude.  Once that was accounted for the output makes sense

Comment: Murphy's Law practically guarantees it would have that value.

Answer (score 0):

I do think you misunderstood the input filter. What is drawn with R it shouldn't exist.

This is how the input filter should loo like.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2favUwX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It isn't an input filter, though, it's the pull-downs for the input pins.  According to the datasheet you need identical pull-downs to handle potential floating inputs.  Unless you meant something else?

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky  I am curious in which datsheet you have found this, because this actually spoils all the principle for what the IA was made for.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič the datasheet for [INA126P](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina126.pdf) does indeed show 47k resistors to the ground as example of current return path for microphone amplifier (figure 20)

Comment: Indeed.  However, the datasheet does not tell you how they computed those values, so I just used 47K and hoped for the best.  If anyone has any information about how to compute a good return path resistor that would be very handy indeed